# include a loop in php for json encode

Tags: php, json, while-loop, encode

I have a problem with my JSON codes. I want to echo this:

```
[{"post_title":"hospital-name","term_taxonomy_id":"15,16,20"}, 
{"post_title":"hospital-name","term_taxonomy_id":"15,16,20"} ]
```

and I coded this :

```
$stmt->execute();
$myarr = array();
while ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $myarr[] = array(
        'post_title' => $data['post_title'],
        'term_taxonomy_id' => $data['term_taxonomy_id'], 
    );
}
echo json_encode($myarr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

but at the end show that :

```
[
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"}
]
```

please help me to solve that.
in fact I have problem with my loop.

Comment: you can use for loop instead of while and check the length of the array.

Comment: first comment code in loop and print your data variable like `print_r($data)` and check the $data values

Comment: Why not `fetch_assoc()`? or `bind_result`?

Comment: so you want based on hospital name `term_taxonomy_id` got concatenated in one comma separated string?Am i right

Comment: $Alive to Die yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you want to get all `term_taxonomy_id` of one hospital in one string as comma separated.

Do like below:-

```
$myarr = array();   
while ($data = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myarr[$data['post_title']] = array(
        'post_title' => $data['post_title'],
        'term_taxonomy_id' => isset($myarr[$data['post_title']]['term_taxonomy_id']) ? $myarr[$data['post_title']]['term_taxonomy_id'].','.$data['term_taxonomy_id'] : $data['term_taxonomy_id']
    );
}
echo json_encode(array_values($myarr), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

A hardcoded example:- https://eval.in/1051696

Reference:- [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)